# google chart data from json not working

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

I trying to get data from json to display on my page using google chart.
when I hardcoded data in my js it was displayed, but why its not showing when I call externaly via json, it says "table has no columns".
why this is happening, any suggestion how to get this works?
thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 function drawChart() {
//  var jsonData ={
// "cols":[
//   {
//    "label":"Unit", 
//    "type":"string"
//   },
//   {
//    "label":"Unit A", 
//    "type":"number"
//   },
//   {
//    "label":"Unit B", 
//    "type":"number"
//   },
//   {
//    "label":"Unit C", 
//    "type":"number"
//   },
//   {
//    "label":"Unit D", 
//    "type":"number"
//   }
//  ],
// "rows":[
//   {
//   "c":[
//     {"v":"02/03/2017"}, 
//     {"v":1.0}, 
//     {"v":10.0},
//     {"v":2.0}, 
//     {"v":4}
//    ]
//   },
//   {
//   "c":[
//     {"v":"02/04/2017"}, 
//     {"v":1.0}, 
//     {"v":10.0},
//     {"v":2.0}, 
//     {"v":4}
//    ]
//   },
//   {
//   "c":[
//     {"v":"02/04/2017"}, 
//     {"v":1.0}, 
//     {"v":10.0},
//     {"v":2.0}, 
//     {"v":4}
//    ]
//   }
//  ]
// };
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "myfile.json",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
   }).responseText;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data);
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine, try validating your JSON file. You can paste your code [here](http://jsonlint.com/) and see if there is sth wrong with your JSON file.

You may be missing a curly bracket at the end.

Comment: I thougt it was additional code to fixed this, as you expect my json cannot read semicolon

Comment: @rnDesto I am facing the same issue, can you please explain how this was fixed.

Comment: @stack_ved have you tried validating your JSON string?